# How to inject strongly typed signalR hub in a class [ASP CORE 2.2]

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I want to inject my strongly typed hub in a service, but I don't like certain thing in the example shown by Microsoft - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-2.2 (Inject a strongly-typed HubContext)

```
public class ChatController : Controller
{
    public IHubContext<ChatHub, IChatClient> _strongChatHubContext { get; }

    public ChatController(IHubContext<ChatHub, IChatClient> chatHubContext)
    {
        _strongChatHubContext = chatHubContext;
    }

    public async Task SendMessage(string message)
    {
        await _strongChatHubContext.Clients.All.ReceiveMessage(message);
    }
}
```

In this example `ChatHub` is coupled to `ChatController`.

So I want to inject the hub itself 
defined with generic interface parameter and no concrete implementation of it will be defined in my service.
This is sample code

```
public interface IReportProcessingClient
{
    Task SendReportInfo(ReportProgressModel report);
}
```

```
public class ReportProcessingHub : Hub<IReportProcessingClient>
{
    public async Task SendMessage(ReportProgressModel report)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendReportInfo(report);
    }
}
```

```
 public class ReportInfoHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
 {
     private readonly Hub<IReportProcessingClient> _hub;
     private readonly IReportGenerationProgressService _reportService;

     public ReportInfoHostedService(Hub<IReportProcessingClient> hub, IReportGenerationProgressService reportService)
     {
         _hub = hub;
         _reportService = reportService;
     }

     public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     {
         _reportService.SubscribeForChange(async x =>
         {
             await _hub.Clients.All.SendReportInfo(x);
         });

         return Task.CompletedTask;
     }

     public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     {
         return Task.CompletedTask;
     }

     public void Dispose()
     {
     }
 }
```

This approach obviously will need additional registration of the hub in Startup.cs as it is not called by the context api provided by Microsoft.

```
services.AddSingleton<Hub<IReportProcessingClient>, ReportProcessingHub>();
```

```
app.UseSignalR(route => {
      route.MapHub<ReportProcessingHub>("/reportProcessingHub");
});
```

All done and working until the hub is trying to send messages to Clients. Then I get the exception

```
_hub.Clients.All threw an exception of System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

So to summerize:

**1. Is this the right way to inject strongly typed hubs and what am I doing wrong(e.g. wrong registration of the hub in services, wrong usage of `app.UseSingleR`)?**

**2. If not, what is the correct way?**

**NOTE:
I know there is a lot easier way injecting `IHubContext<Hub<IReportProcessingClient>>`, but this is not a solution for me, because I have to call the hub method name passed as `string` parameter.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want to ... and no concrete implementation of it will be defined in my service

1. If you don't want to expose a concrete hub implementation, you should at least expose **a base class** or **interface**. However, since a hub should inherit from the `Hub` class, we can't use an interface here. So let's create a public base hub `ReportProcessingHubBase` as well as an internal concrete `ReportProcessingHub`:

   ```cs
   public abstract class ReportProcessingHubBase : Hub<IReportProcessingClient>
   {
       public abstract Task SendMessage(ReportProgressModel report);
   }

   // the concrete hub will NOT be exposed
   internal class ReportProcessingHub : ReportProcessingHubBase
   {
       public override async Task SendMessage(ReportProgressModel report)
       {
           await Clients.All.SendReportInfo(report);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Make sure you've registered the two related service:

   ```cs
   services.AddScoped<ReportProcessingHubBase, ReportProcessingHub>();
   services.AddHostedService<ReportInfoHostedService>();
   ```
3. Make sure you're mapping the **Base Hub** (**MOST IMPORTANT!**):

   ```cs
    endpoints.MapHub<ReportProcessingHubBase>("/report");
   ```
4. Finally, you can get the base hub by injecting `IHubContext<ReportProcessingHubBase,IReportProcessingClient>` :

   ```
   public class ReportInfoHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
   {
       private readonly IHubContext<ReportProcessingHubBase,IReportProcessingClient> _hub;

       public ReportInfoHostedService(IHubContext<ReportProcessingHubBase,IReportProcessingClient> hub)
       {
           _hub = hub;
       }

       ...
    }
   ```

   Now, you can invoking the hub method in a strongly-typed way.